# How can I install Apache Ant 1.9.5 and connect it to Android Studio 1.2.1.1 in Windows 8.1?

Tags: java, android, ant, android-studio

I was able to install Apache Ant, but I don't know how to connect it to Java.

- How can I connect Apache Ant to my Java installation?
- How can I connect Apache Ant to Android Studio for Mobile App Development?
- Do I even need to connect Ant to Android Studio to do this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline-ant.html

Comment: Why aren't you using Gradle?  It's built into Android Studio and is currently the preferred method of building Android applications.  Gradle was designed to combine the best of Ant and Maven into a single build system using Groovy as the DSL.

Comment: I tried to connect my html file to Gradle, but I couldn't figure out how.  How can I connect it to Gradle when I already created the App in html?